# Unknown Size of HashMap | Passing Dynamic Functions into Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, rust

I've written a program to process my financial transactions but it's starting to run a little slower now that I'm adding more data to it.  I decided to write it in Rust.  I'm fluent in JS, TS, Python, bash/shell scripting.  I need to feed the entire history into the application at this time.  Currently my program is single-threaded.  My thought is that if I use multi-threading strategically I should be able to cut the run-time down.

Here is how I attempted to implement multi-threading:

```rust
    for row in lines[1..].iter() {
        thread::spawn(|| {
            process_transaction(row, &rules) 
        });
    }
```

Rules is a hashmap that looks like this.

```rust
type CustomRule = Box<dyn Fn(&Transaction) -> &'static str>;
type RuleHashMap = HashMap<&'static str, CustomRule>;
```

Row is a Transaction structure w/ stuff and some functions implemented into it.  (Regex, gt/lt matching)
The key will be a regex string and the value will be that custom function.  This custom function has to be put in a Box because it's size needs to go onto the heap?
The idea is that I should be able to just quickly iterate over a set of regex patterns then run the corresponding additional logic needed to process that transaction.  I am not mutating Transaction or Rules in any way and I'm only printing a result.  Here's an example rule:

```rust
        rules.insert(r"(?i)7-ELEVEN|EXXONMOBIL|CIRCLE K|SUNOCO|SHEETZ|A-PLUS|RACEWAY|SHELLSERVICE|Shell SERVICE|QUICK NEASY|QUICK N EASY|FAS MART|BP|ROYAL MART|CITG|gas|wawa", Box::new(|t:&Transaction|{
            match t.less_than(15.0) {
                true => "expenses:convience",
                false => "expenses:business:gas"
            } 
        }));
```

The compiler suggested I update the type to implement Send

```rust
type CustomRule = dyn Fn(&Transaction) + Send + 'static;
```

I added that but now it says it does not know the size of the HashMap at compile time.  I get this message from the compiler

```
= help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r Transaction) + Send + 'static)`
note: required by a bound in `HashMap`
```

What is this?  I'm new to lower level programming like this and I want to understand what is actually happening versus just copying blindly.  Especially when playing w/ threads.  Was putting that custom rule function into a `Box<>` type the wrong move?  Am I making this more complicated than needed.

Comment: You second `CustomRule` is not boxed, so is not sized.

Comment: Side note: you can use the [Rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/) crate which would allow you to do parallel iteration without having to manually create threads.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your closures are "pure" functions that don't capture any state, then you can just store fn pointers in your map instead:

```rust
let mut rules: HashMap<&'static str, fn(&Transaction) -> &'static str> = HashMap::new();
rules.insert(r"some long regex", |t: &Transaction|{
    "expenses:convience"
});
```

You say

> The idea is that I should be able to just quickly iterate over a set of regex patterns then run the corresponding additional logic needed to process that transaction.

If you're actually iterating, why even use a `HashMap`? Just use a `Vec` or array of tuples like so:

```rust
let mut rules: [(&'static str, fn(&Transaction) -> &'static str); 1] = [
    (r"some long regex", |t: &Transaction|{
        "expenses:convience"
    }),
];
```

You probably also should compile the Regexs only once, rather than compiling and running them every time. I recommend putting them in statics with [`once_cell::sync::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html).